# How to share common code across analyses in R

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I’ve copied codes into parent and child file and located the child as  C:/temp/child.Rmd
The statements in parent program

````
---
title: "parent"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)

library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
```

```{r, parent, include = FALSE}
src <- lapply(
  sort(unique(iris$Species)), 
  FUN = function(x) {
    knitr::knit_expand(
      file = here::here("C:/temp/child.Rmd"), 
      title = x
    )
  }
)
```
`r knitr::knit(text = unlist(src))`

The statements in child program
---
title: "child1"
output: pdf_document
---
## {{title}}

```{r plot_{{title}}}
iris %>%
  filter(Species == "{{title}}") %>%
  ggplot() +
  aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(title = "{{title}}")
```
````

When I knit the parent program, the error message as below. Why and how to fix it?

```
Quitting from lines 14-23 (trypc.Rmd) 
Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
Calls: <Anonymous> ... one_string -> paste -> read_utf8 -> readLines -> file
Execution halted
```

Thanks

Comment: Don't use here on an absolute path.

Comment: Thank you.  I  ran  the code  after  removing here, same issue happens and connection still can't open.

Comment: If you're using an absolute path to the child, you're not using the functionality of the `here` package. I'd remove the here() or revert to a relative path using here()